# How to use Horizontal data saved in a table as Columns in postgres

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, entity-attribute-value

I have a table like this:

Table VR

```
ID  Key         Value   Date
123 First_Name  Vlad    01-01-2011
234 First_Name  Jim     07-01-2011
456 First_Name  Olimpia 10-02-2012
123 Last_Name   Kofman  12-02-2014
234 Last_Name   Cramer  14-02-2014
456 Last_Name   Dukakis 04-03-2015
123 Dept    IT          08-03-2016
234 Dept    Marketing
456 Dept    Accounting
123 Sex M
234 Sex M
456 Sex F
```

Now, I want to write a query to get the Value where First_Name ='Vlad' AND Last_Name='Cramer'.
Another Scenarios is I want to fetch all the records between the date '01-01-2011' to '14-02-2016'.

The query I wrote is:

```
SELECT VR.key,
      Min(( CASE
              WHEN ( VR.key = 'FIRST_NAME' ) THEN
             VR.value
              ELSE 'n/a'
            END )) AS first_name,
      Min(( CASE
              When ( VR.key = 'LAST_NAME' ) THEN
              VR.value
              ELSE 'n/a'
            END )) AS last_name
FROM   VR
WHERE   ( ( VR.first_name = 'Vlad' )
          AND ( VR.last_name = 'Cramer' ) )
GROUP  BY VR.key
ORDER  BY VR.first_name,
VR.last_name
```

The exception I am getting is Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column VR.first_name does not exist;

Can anyone please help me getting how should I achieve the desired result.

Comment: Please tag only the one database that you are using (you have both `mysql` and `postgres`, which are two different databases). From the error message, it looks like you are actually running amazon-redshift - there is a specific tag for this database.

Comment: Edited the tags

Comment: got to love writing SQL to wrangle data in an EAV model ...   what exactly does the "desired result" look like? what do we expect returned?  are these attribute rows at all linked by the `id` column ... are we supposed to be viewing this as if this was tuples (rows) like `(123,'Vlad','Kofman','M','IT',...)` and `(234,'Jim','Cramer','M','Marketing',...)` and `(456,'Olympia','Dukakis','F','Accounting',...)` and writing a query that would return what? given broken sql as a specification, we are just guessing ...

Comment: @spencer7593 for your understanding I modified my question, actually I need to fetch all the records between the date range '01-01-2011' to '14-02-2016' and it has nothing to do with first_name and last_name. Can you help me with its query.?

Comment: It's still not clear what "fetch all the records" looks like. The question gives no example of what the result set to be returned looks like. If we want to fetch all the records between two dates, then we could do `SELECT t* FROM VR t WHERE t.Date >= '2011-01-01' AND t.Date < '2016-02-15'` , but I suspect (given the SQL in the question) that isn't really the resultset we are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table does not have a columns called `first_name` or `last_name` - these are values in the `key` column.

I think that you are actually looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select id
from vr
where key in ('First_Name', 'Last_Name')
group by id
having 
    max(case when key = 'First_Name' and value = 'Vlad' then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when key = 'Last_Name' and value = 'Cramer' then 1 end) = 1
```

This gives you `id`s that have their first name equal to Vlad and last name equal to Cramer.

Comment: can you please look into this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158654/how-to-fetch-records-using-vertical-columns-in-amazon-redshift

Answer (score 1):

You should build from your VR Table a regular table and use that as starting point to make your query or build a view from that inner SELECT

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        VR.id,
            MAX(IF(VR.key = 'First_Name', VR.Value, NULL)) 'First_Name',
            MAX(IF(VR.key = 'Last_Name', VR.Value, NULL)) 'Last_Name',
            MAX(IF(VR.key = 'Dept', VR.Value, NULL)) 'Dept',
            MAX(IF(VR.key = 'Sex M', 'male', IF(VR.key = 'Sex F', 'female', NULL))) 'Gender'
    FROM
        VR
    GROUP BY VR.id) comp
WHERE
    First_Name = 'Vlad'
        AND Last_Name = 'Kofman';
```

> ```
>  id | First_Name | Last_Name | Dept | Gender
> --: | :--------- | :-------- | :--- | :-----
> 123 | Vlad       | Kofman    | IT   | male
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c2b38de04f6ddf8770e5e625ac6d208f)*