# How to fetch records using vertical columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to fetch records between the date range given in two columns.

My Table structure is like:

```
CREATE TABLE shared
(
   id         integer         NOT NULL,
   product          varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
   parent_id  integer         NOT NULL,
   key_code         varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
   key_value        varchar(8000)
);

INSERT INTO shared
    (`id`, `product`, `parent_id`, 'key_code', 'key_value')
VALUES
    (1, 'a',1, 'start_date','1/7/2011'),
    (2, 'a', 1,'end_date','15/7/2011'),
    (3, 'a',1, 'type','Promotion'),
    (4, 'a',1,'plan', 'new'),
    (5, 'a',5, 'start_date','11/8/2012'),
    (6, 'a', 5,'end_date','15/8/2012'),
    (7, 'a',5, 'type','Promotion'),
    (8, 'a',5,'plan', 'new'),
    (9, 'b',9, 'start_date','15/09/2015'),
    (10, 'b', 9,'end_date','15/09/2016'),
    (11, 'b',9, 'type','Promotion'),
    (12, 'b',9,'plan', 'new'),
;
```

Now i want to fetch all the records between start date>='1/7/2011' to start_date<='15/8/2012' where product='a'.

The Query I tried is:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT   parent_id,
         product,
          MIN(CASE WHEN key_code = 'key_code' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS key_code,
          MIN(CASE WHEN key_code = 'start_date' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS start_date,
          MIN(CASE WHEN key_code = 'end_date' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS end_date,
          MIN(CASE WHEN key_code = 'type' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS type,
          MIN(CASE WHEN key_code = 'plan' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS plan,
FROM     shared
GROUP BY parent_id,
         product
ORDER BY parent_id) comp
WHERE
    start_date>= '01/12/2011'
        AND start_date <= '02/17/2011' and product='a';
```

I am getting records now, changed the date format.

But is there any way to optimize this query.? Like this will take time to execute when records are in numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates have not the MySQL format, so they have to be converted,to be compared

With the MIN and MAX and your 'n/a, it is better to use NULL in the inner Select and in the outer assign the Value n/a if the value is NULL, ot or else you get n/qa even if there is data.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        parent_id,
            product,
            MIN(CASE WHEN key_code = 'start_date' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS start_date,
            MIN(CASE WHEN key_code = 'end_date' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS end_date,
            MAX(CASE WHEN key_code = 'type' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS type,
            MAX(CASE WHEN key_code = 'plan' THEN key_value ELSE 'n/a' END) AS plan
    FROM
        shared
    GROUP BY parent_id , product
    ORDER BY parent_id) comp
WHERE
    TO_DATE(start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= '2011-01-12'
        AND TO_DATE(start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= '2011-07-17'
        AND product = 'a'
;
```

Thsi would give youz

```
 parent_id  product  start_date  end_date   type        plan
 1          a        1/7/2011    15/7/2011  Promotion   new
```

So STR:TO:DATE doesn't exist in AWS but it EXISTS a [TO_Date](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html)
Instead of IF you maust do  A CASe when like in your query

Comment: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function if(boolean, character varying, "unknown") does not exist;
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function str_to_date(text, "unknown") does not exist;
I guess if and str_to_date syntax is not supported in Amazon Redshift

Comment: So i changed it the if clause  was replaced by CASE WHEN ölike i your query and teh -str_TO_DAte i replaced with with TO_DATE